# How to encode an arbitrary command to a exec form in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

In Dockerfile, `RUN` has 2 forms:

- `RUN <command>` (the command is run in a shell - /bin/sh -c - shell form)
- `RUN ["executable", "param1", "param2"]` (exec form)

How to encode `>`, `>>`, `<`, `&&` `||` as a exec form?

---

This is a very simple dockerfile. I want to rewrite `RUN <command>` as exec form.
But I don't know how.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN date > /tmp/out && echo 'hello world' >> /tmp/out
CMD cat /tmp/out
```

Comment: Could you give some context describing what is behind this request?  It reads like "given two choices, A and B, I want to do A, but by doing B", which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/run:

> Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen.

I therefore think that there is no direct way to use these shell-interpreted characters (such as  `>`, `>>`, `<`, `&&`, `||`) in the exec form.